# When other site posts to my site, I receive "The resource you are looking for has been removed...." error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure, post, azure-web-app-service

I am newer to angular and azure setups. I have a simple jade login form that is posting to a URL (different origin than my website) on submit. For security purposes, I have substituted the URL for a sample one.

```
form(name='loginForm' id="loginForm" method="post" action="https://www.test.userloginauth.com/test")
  .form-group
    input(type='text' name='user' class='form-control' required id='loginUser')
   .form-group
     input(type='password' name='pw' class='form-control' required id='loginPw')
    div.hidden
      input(type='hidden' name='site' value='gf')
    .login
      button(class='custom-button' name='Submit' type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit') Sign In
```

The `https://www.test.userloginauth.com/test` url validates the login, and if the user is valid, sends the user to my test page: `https://www.test.mysite.com/loggedin`. *(Note: this page is /loggedin/index.jade - not sure if that matters or not. I have also tried /loggedin/test.jade.)* Then `https://www.test.userloginauth.com/test` also sends a `POST` back to this page that has the user's ID.

I typed in a valid user and was correctly redirected to `https://www.test.mysite.com/loggedin` as expected. The problem is that I am receiving this 404-error **`"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."`** and I am not sure why. This only happens when `https://www.test.userloginauth.com/test` posts to my site, and the `https://www.test.mysite.com/loggedin` page loads perfectly if you go to it directly.

Is there something I could be missing from my `web.config` file? Here is what I have tried:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,DELETE,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Olaround-Debug-Mode, Authorization, Accept, Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="X-Olaround-Debug-Mode, X-Olaround-Request-Start-Timestamp, X-Olaround-Request-End-Timestamp, X-Olaround-Request-Time, X-Olaround-Request-Method, X-Olaround-Request-Result, X-Olaround-Request-Endpoint" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To confirm, what's your application's structure? Are you using expressjs as backend server, and leveraging jade template with angular modules as frontend?

Comment: Hello @GaryLiu-MSFT. Yes, you are correct.

Comment: did you configure CORS? This would need to be done on the app hosting the target URL

Comment: Hi @clo_, do you have any update for now?

Comment: Hi @GaryLiu-MSFT. I am still working through this. It is one piece of a much larger project so I got caught up on other parts. I tried allowing CORS but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT: Another person suggested that I set this up differently. Instead of posting in the Jade, I now call a function in my ctrl on Submit. This calls the server side JS. Here I app.post & request post to the https://www.test.userloginauth.com/test URL. I can see the response from this URL but it shows me the entire HTML of the form they post back to me. They are posting back to: https://www.test.mysite.com/loggedin with hidden field user ID. I'm not sure how to access the user's ID. I tried response.body and got the HTML form they post back. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be a logic issue of the previous link, does it have any redirect logic? You may check out in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

According your error messages, you can try to check the following two points:

- Whether you have implement functionality for `loggedin` and expose it as a post route rule.
- Whether you have config the correct configurations in your `web.config`, e.g. there is a `server.js` in your root directory as the entrance of your application.
  Then in your `web.config` should contains following content:

  ```
  <handlers>
    <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
  </handlers>
  <rules>
      <clear />
      <rule name="DynamicContent">
            <conditions>
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
      </rule>
  </rules>
  ```

  Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.